# Tabulator column with JSX - executing class functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tabulator

I'm trying to use react-tabulator but I'm having troubles rendering a function inside my table columns.
The function is returning JSX but it is using other class functions, which fails to execute.
[image: pic]
basically, the column "actions" has 2 icons, edit and delete, each of them is an icon component with onClick property which calls a **function** inside my class. The **function** fails to execute because "this" is undefined, so the function **couldn't be found**.

here is my code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {reactFormatter, ReactTabulator} from 'react-tabulator'
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import {IconsDiv} from "./styles";
import {FontAwesomeIcon} from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import {faPencilAlt, faTrash} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

class MyTable extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        teamsTableData: this.createFormattedData([1,2]),
        rowID: 0,  
    };
    this.options = {
        movableColumns: true,
        pagination: "local",
        paginationSize: 15,
    };

    this.ref = null;
    this.handleEdit = this.handleEdit.bind(this);
    this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
}
 createFormattedData(data) {
    return {
        rows: data.map(ele => {
                return {
                    id: ele.teamId,
                    name: "test1",
                    count: "test1",
                };
            }
        ),
        columns: [
            {
                title: "Name", field: "name",
                headerFilter: "input",
            }, 
            {
                title: "Count", field: "count",
                headerFilter: "input",
                headerFilterFunc: "=",
            },
            {
                title: "Actions", field: "actions",
                formatter: reactFormatter(<this.createActions/>),
            }
        ],
    }
}
  createActions(table) {
    const rowData = table.cell._cell.row.data;
    return <IconsDiv>
        <IconButton onClick={() => this.handleEdit(rowData)}>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPencilAlt} className={'Icon'}/>
        </IconButton>
        {" "}
        <IconButton onClick={() => this.handleDelete(rowData)}>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrash} className='Icon'/>
        </IconButton>
    </IconsDiv>;
}
 handleEdit(rowData) {
    this.setState({rowID: rowData.id});
}
handleDelete(rowData) {
        this.setState({deleteRow: rowData.id});
    }

render() {
    return (
        <>
            <ReactTabulator
                ref={ref => (this.ref = ref)}
                data={this.state.teamsTableData.rows}
                columns={this.state.teamsTableData.columns}
                tooltips={true}
                options={this.options}
                layout={"fitColumns"}
            />
        </>
    )
}
}
```

Does anyone know what is wrong? why the column is rendered properly, but the action fails? why does "this.handleEdit" or "this.handleDelete" couldn't be found? ( I guess "this" is undefined)

Answer (score 0):

You can assign `this` to another variable so you can pass the scope into the function:

```js
  createActions(table) {
    var self = this; //assign this to the self variable and pass into the icons

    const rowData = table.cell._cell.row.data;
    return <IconsDiv>
        <IconButton onClick={() => self.handleEdit(rowData)}>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPencilAlt} className={'Icon'}/>
        </IconButton>
        {" "}
        <IconButton onClick={() => self.handleDelete(rowData)}>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrash} className='Icon'/>
        </IconButton>
    </IconsDiv>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using an arrow function instead?

```
createActions = (table) => {

    const rowData = table.cell._cell.row.data;
    return <IconsDiv>
        <IconButton onClick={() => this.handleEdit(rowData)}>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPencilAlt} className={'Icon'}/>
        </IconButton>
        {" "}
        <IconButton onClick={() => this.handleDelete(rowData)}>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrash} className='Icon'/>
        </IconButton>
    </IconsDiv>;
}
```